# isbn search in android

Tags: android, search, isbn

i wanna search book name using its isbn number..
how to impliment in android???

thnx in advance......

Answer (score 1):

1. Find a service that enables you to search books via ISDN: for example http://isbndb.com/data-intro.html
2. Make a HTTP request with the help of HttpClient: http://w3mentor.com/learn/java/android-development/android-http-services/example-of-http-get-request-using-httpclient-in-android/
3. Parse the reply. In this case it's XML: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-android/

Comment: : can this work in phonegap???

Comment: I'm not familiar with phonegap, so I don't know.